# Having issues with audio quality when I play it through my Focusrite Audio Interface

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, interface

#### Main Problem

I have a USB audio interface (Focusrite Scarlett Solo 2nd-gen) for headphones. When I play audio through my audio interface, It sounds like a chip tune song or like an 80s video game. [This is what It sounds like](https://youtu.be/ubCMI3Jq6e4?t=98)

To be clear there is nothing wrong with my Audio Interface or my headphones I tested it on windows. It works just fine.

---

#### Other

This problem doesn't exist when I change the output device.

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release?  Which? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, use `audacious` and select Output Plugin as PulseAudio Automatic bit depth then tell us, which music player and Your Ubuntu OS version.

Comment: Information from review site, please set input gain Zero and try to play some music.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka It didn't work. Same problem.  I am using Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: @waltinator I am using 21.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Scarlett 2i2 on Ubuntu 20.04, this worked for me:

1. Open `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` with your text editor, example: `sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`
2. Find the lines with `default-sample-format` and `default-sample-rate` and remove the `;` in front of them. I also had to change the value of `default-sample-rate` to `48000` from `44100`. I left the value of `default-sample-format` as `s16le`. Save and exit.
3. restart pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k`

Comment: worked :) but its still not perfect sound....

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem with ubuntu studio 20.4.4.
Oddest thing is that I can plug a a mic or bass guitar and use direct monitor and it plays back normally, but when I use applications like Spotify or my Browser it sounds like you described it.

Comment: Hello. This is not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: well i cant add comments because i need reputation for that which doesnt make any sense mate.

Comment: Please lmk if you found an answer